# Render SharpDX.Direct2D1.Effects.Brightness on WinForm surface

Tags: c#, winforms, render, direct2d, sharpdx

need HELP :)
I`m writing software that renders h264 stream, using ffmpeg for decoding and SharpDx for rendering. Now I need to make the picture brighter using dx, but my Render Target cannot do it. I use SharpDX.Direct2D1.WindowRenderTarget by passing Hwnd of PictureBox and it has only DrawBitmap(...) method, whereas I need DrawImage(...) method.

From this: https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Direct2D1/OfflineImageProcessingApp/Program.cs
example I can apply brightness effect to WIC bitmap read from PNG file and save it to file, but how I can render it to surface?

Comment: You can try to call QueryInterface<DeviceContext> on your render target

Comment: @SimonMourier, thank you so much. It`s able to render Image now. But may be you know how i can create SharpDX.Direct2D1.Effects.Brightness object from IntPtr that points bitmap array?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. An effect cannot be created from a bitmap array

Comment: @SimonMourier, I mean the following: to create an effect i should have wic bitmap source, but i got only pointer to bitmap data after decoding frame. How i can create bitmap source? I try google it, but didn't find anything.

Comment: i tried to create an WIC.Bitmap object and then use its property DataLock.DataPointer, and it`s work, but is it most efficient way?

Comment: WIC bitmap(source) (stored in CPU RAM) and D2D1 bitmaps (stored in GPU RAM) are two different things. Show some code, what you're doing is far from clear.